# Use of encoder in Domain Class initialisation

Tags: hibernate, grails

interesting problem:

I have a Domain Class which looks like

```
class Dummy {
    String key = (''+new Date()).encodeAsSHA256()
}
```

When I try to start my App, I get a long stacktrace / error message stating

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: could not instantiate test objectmad.Dummy
...
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.encodeAsSHA256() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

now, if I remove the `.encodeAsSHA256()`, start the application in dev mode and re-insert the encode, it works :-)

So basically, the code works @ runtime, but it seems that @ initialisation time, the String class isn't ready for the encoders yet.

Any idea how I can fix this without creating a custom constructor?

Comment: Unrelated - never use `"" + something` to string-ify something, since you're unnecessarily using a StringBuilder to do something that's very simple. Just call `String.valueOf(something)` or `something.toString()`

Comment: Thanx. A shortcut for `toString()` would be a nice add on for groovy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found a solution: the encoder can also be invoked directly, but you have to know the right package...

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.codecs.SHA256Codec

class Dummy {
    String key = SHA256Codec.encode(''+new Date())
}
```

...solves the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Why *not* a constructor? This belongs in a constructor...

Comment: My experience is, that if I create a constructor, I lose the great grails default constructor...

Comment: I haven't seen that at all. You can always call super() too. I frequently set defaults in a constructor in grails domain objects.

Comment: It's the same thing - these end up in the constructor. The compiler moves the initialization from the field to the constructor (Java and Groovy).